# Laravel compare models and cast attributes

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working inside a Laravel 10 application and am building a notification feature designed to notify users when significant columns on various models change. I've got a global model observer set up which contains these methods, when a model is updated I want to compare the original against the current.

My issue is that `getAttributes()` isn't casting my columns on my model, for example, my `Buyer` model does indeed define a correct `casts` property *(we can see this from getOriginal() working)*

How can I ensure the values are casted / compared correctly:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Jobs\ProcessModelObserver;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Exception;

class GlobalModelObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the User "created" event.
     */
    public function created($model): void
    {
        try {
            ProcessModelObserver::dispatch($model, $model->id, 'created', Carbon::now());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the User "updated" event.
     */
    public function updated($model): void
    {
        try {
            $originalAttributes = $model->getOriginal();
            $currentAttributes = $model->getAttributes();

            $columnsToExclude = [
                'id',
                'description',
                'is_favourited',
                'last_used_at',
                'updated_at',
                'created_at',
                'type',
                'last_built_at',
                'last_successful_build_at',
                'last_failed_build_at',
                'slug'
            ];

            $originalAttrs = collect($model->getOriginal())->reject(function ($value, $key) use ($columnsToExclude) {
                return in_array($key, $columnsToExclude);
            })->sort()->all();

            $currentAttrs = collect($model->getAttributes())->reject(function ($value, $key) use ($columnsToExclude) {
                return in_array($key, $columnsToExclude);
            })->sort()->all();

            $numDifferences = count(collect($originalAttrs)->diffAssoc(collect($currentAttrs))->toArray());

            // only dispatch if there are differences
            if ($numDifferences > 0) {
                ProcessModelObserver::dispatch($model, $model->id, 'updated', Carbon::now(), [
                    'model' => [
                        'original' => collect($originalAttrs)->toArray(),
                        'current' => collect($currentAttrs)->toArray()
                    ]
                ]);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::debug("cannot send update notification", [
                'e' => $e->getMessage(),
                'f' => $e->getFile(),
                'l' => $e->getLine()
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the User "deleted" event.
     */
    public function deleted($model): void
    {
        try {
            ProcessModelObserver::dispatch($model, $model->id, 'deleted', Carbon::now());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the User "force deleted" event.
     */
    public function forceDeleted($model): void
    {
        try {
            ProcessModelObserver::dispatch($model, $model->id, 'deleted', Carbon::now());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This code, outputs the following JSON:

```json
{
   "model":{
      "original":{
         "is_default":false,
         "dedupe_is_enabled":false,
         "dedupe_value":0,
         "dedupe_accepts":false,
         "deleted_at":null,
         "user_id":1,
         "company_id":1,
         "product_id":1,
         "name":"TUK",
         "is_enabled":true,
         "dedupe_period":"days"
      },
      "current":{
         "is_default":0,
         "dedupe_is_enabled":0,
         "dedupe_value":0,
         "dedupe_accepts":0,
         "deleted_at":null,
         "user_id":1,
         "company_id":1,
         "product_id":1,
         "is_enabled":1,
         "name":"TUK",
         "dedupe_period":"days"
      }
   }
}
```

What do I need to change please?

Comment: have you tried using `->getDirty()` on the model?

Comment: Have you tried using  $model->getChanges() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start by implementing an interface on your models to make life easier

```php
interface ListenForChanges
{
    public function excludeFromListener(): array;
}
```

```php
class User extends Model implements ListensForChanges
{
  public function excludeFromListener(): array
  {
    return [
      // fields to exclude for each model
    ];
  }
}
```

than we can update your global observer like so:

```php
public function updated($model): void
{
  if ($model instanceof ListensForChanges) {
    $changes = Arr::except($model->getDirty(), $model->excludeFromListener())
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this take into account casts? For example, would current / historic changes be casted?

Comment: it will take casts into account when comparing. If you check the implementation of `getDirty()` it uses `->originalIsEquivalent($key)` to compare each attribute of the model.

Comment: Where am I importing `ListensForChanges` from? Can't find it in the docs?

Comment: it's just an interface you can create that defines the `excludeFromListener` method, so that on the global observer you know if a model has that method, without knowing what type of model it is exactly, and you want to listen to it's changes.

Comment: So it just works without importing?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the interface also @RyanH

Comment: When I make a change now after implementing the changes you've described, and adding some fields to my exclude on my model, I've put a `Log::debug` inside the `if` statement and I'm not getting any logs for that? Why might this be?

Comment: does the model you changed implement the interface? Try increasing the log level to info or warning? Did you put a log outside the if condition too?

Comment: Yes, the method exists, and outside of the `if` statement it works, unless the model doesn't contain the method and then it throws an error (thus why you've added the instance of check). How would I ensure that the method exists? Try/catch maybe?

Comment: The model needs to implement the interface, not just copy the method

Comment: Model is implementing the interface: `class Affiliate extends Model implements ListenForChangesContract`, I renamed it for reference. A try/catch works lovely. Must be something else going on?

Comment: hmm, not sure, you might want to log the caught error

Comment: @RyanH can you mark this as solved please